# Is there a good component to prevent dos attack or hacking for 3.X branch of Joomla?

Tags: security

I wonder if there is a good component to inspect my `Joomla` websites made on the 3.x branche.

On dedicated servers Joomla directory structure is frequently attacked by `eval` code or file `SQL injection`.

Is there a good component to avoid malwares and intrusion (like a firewall) and to inspect the whole vulnerabilies ?

Comment: I asked something (sort of) similar and there were some great answers here http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/14696/site-vulnerability-check/14697#14697 - this might help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A component cannot prevent a DOS or DDOS attack.

Actually it is a good practice to make a separation of concerns. You website (or let us call it web application) has the role of providing business value to your customers.

At another level, a web application firewall (WAF) and/or intrusion detection system (IDS), is another system in your network infrastructure responsible for such security aspects.

PHP should not have to deal with such things. It is not really the best tool.

If you are on a low budget look into a hoster that already provides such a protection. Some of them do this already  (for example Siteground). Or you may want to have a look at what www.cloudflare.com has to offer for free.

Be sure to check out the [presentation from Tony Perez](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_H2ez7EyEyg) at the Joomla World Conference 2015.